# Live Edit using WebStorm for Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, webstorm, liveedit

Is there a plugin for WebStorm that facilitates live editing for Firefox?

The equivalent for Chrome would be: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7007.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a workaround using a JS package named [livereload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/livereload). It autorefresh Firefox (or any browser) automagically when saving your WebStorm project.

The simplest way to run it is:

1. Add this boilerplate temporarily to your site (you won't want it for production)

```js
<script>
  document.write('<script src="http://' + 
    (location.host || 'localhost').split(':')[0] +
    ':35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></' + 'script>')
</script>
```

2. From your WebStorm console:

```
$ npm install -g livereload
$ livereload [path of files to watch]
```

Answer (score 2):

No, Live Edit only works in Chrome. Please follow [WEB-1805](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-1805) for updates

Answer (score 2):

You may also use [browser-sync](https://browsersync.io/).

It only requires two simple steps:

1. install npm package: npm install -g browser-sync
2. start browser-sync

> A basic use is to watch all CSS files in the css directory and update
>   connected browsers if a change occurs. Navigate your terminal window
>   to a project and run the appropriate command:

**Static sites**

If you’re only using .html files, you’ll need to use the *server mode*. Browsersync will start a mini-server and provide a URL to view your site.

```
browser-sync start --server --files "css/*.css"
```

**Dynamic sites**

If you’re already running a local server with PHP or similar, you’ll need to use the *proxy mode*. Browsersync will wrap your vhost with a proxy URL to view your site.

```
browser-sync start --proxy "myproject.dev" --files "css/*.css"
```

You can add other file types as a comma separated list

```
--files "*.html, css/*.css"
```